# Using SQL query in R for loop with variable names in filter

Tags: r, postgresql

I am trying to call a SQL query from a for loop in R where one of the query filters will be using an R variable. I tried various ways -one shown below- and can't seem to make this work. The database is PostgreSQL. Can this be done? What am I doing wrong?

```
plants <- c("Kansas" ,"Atlanta", "New York")
for (i in 1:3) {
 tbl1 <- dbGetQuery(dbicon, "SELECT facility_code, test_name FROM qds.tests where facility_code IN $plants[i]" )
  df_tbl1 <- as.data.frame(tbl1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use R functions to build the query string. You can do this with `paste`, `sprintf`, the `glue` package, or other ways of manipulating strings. Here's a couple examples:

```
plants <- c("Kansas" ,"Atlanta", "New York")
for (i in 1:3) {
  qry <- sprintf(
    "SELECT facility_code, test_name FROM qds.tests where facility_code IN ('%s') LIMIT 5",
    plants[i]
  )
  tbl1 <- dbGetQuery(dbicon, qry)
  df_tbl1 <- as.data.frame(tbl1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to install a package to use sprintf? I tried what you suggested above with my actual plant parameters ("TN705" and "TX405") and got the error message: Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42601: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"; Error while preparing parameters RROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"; Error while preparing parameters <SQL> 'SELECT facility_code, test_name FROM qds.tests LIMIT 5 WHERE facility_code IN TN705'

Comment: No, `sprintf` is a base R function. As for the error, it's probably because I left out the quotes around the IN item. Editing now.

Comment: I put the quotes around %s ('%s') as your edit shows and still getting the same error - just with quotes around my plant name. Any thoughts? I feel we are close but maybe not? Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42601: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"; Error while preparing parameters RROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"; Error while preparing parameters <SQL> 'SELECT facility_code, test_name FROM qds.tests LIMIT 5 WHERE facility_code IN 'TN705''

Comment: It looks like valid SQL to me, not sure why it's throwing an error.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question - I really don't know much about SQL and only needing to access data in it from R: I am told our data is in PostgreSQL - could that have a different context?'

Comment: Hmm, I actually think the issue is the `LIMIT 5`. That should go at the end of the query, after the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I deleted the LIMIT 5 and instead limited the data (otherwise would take forever to run) by adding another WHERE clause (to limit date range). Getting this error: 
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42601: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'TN705'"; Error while preparing parameters RROR: syntax error at or near "'TN705'"; Error while preparing parameters <SQL> 'SELECT facility_code, test_name, result_on_date_key FROM qds.tests WHERE result_on_date_key >= 20211101 AND facility_code IN 'TN705''

Comment: I don't think you need to delete the `LIMIT 5`, I think you need to move it to be **after** `where facility_code IN '%s'`. My SQL is rusty - you may also need parentheses for the `IN` - edited the answer.